# How to exclude file to execute hook?

Tags: emacs

I have in this my config file:

```
(defun untabify-everything ()
  (untabify (point-min) (point-max)))
(defun untabify-everything-on-save ()
  (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'untabify-everything) nil)
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'untabify-everything-on-save)
```

but I want to exclude "Makefile" from this. How to do this?

Comment: 1. Why are you running untabify twice via `before-save-hook`? 2. Change your function `untabify-everything` to untabify the buffer only if the `buffer-file-name` does not match `Makefile`.

Comment: FWIW this really sounds like a terrible idea to me (and the same applies to almost any kind of reformat-the-file-upon-save behaviour).  I would urge you to instead configure the default value of `indent-tabs-mode` to be `nil` so that Emacs does not *create* tabs for indentation; and to deal with any existing unwanted tabs in files as a one-time fix.